# Extending duration of stay to more than 90 days with 1-year Schengen visa in Greece

Tags: schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

I have a type ‘C’ Schengen visa valid from June 9 2019 - June 8 2020. In September, I will be going to Thessaloniki in Greece to observe in a hospital (I work in healthcare), supposedly for 6 months. The Greek consul in my country advised me to use my current Schengen visa for this trip.

However, I know the maximum length of stay is 90 days.

My question is, while in Greece, can I apply for an extension to the 90-day stay? I know you can apply to extend if your visa is expiring, but mine is not. I just want to extend the length of stay.

Comment: What is shown as the ΤΥΠΟΣ ΘΕΩΡΗΣΗΣ (TYPE OF VISA)?

Comment: It's a tourist visa, multiple entry

Comment: They put "tourist" there? I would expect it to show "C"

Comment: Sorry, yes it's "C"

Comment: To stay longer than 90 days in Greece, you need either a type-D visa issued by Greece (before you arrive there) or a residence permit issued in Greece (after you arrive there).  Some Schengen countries prohibit residence permit applications from people with C visas, requiring instead that you have a D visa.  I do not know how it works in Greece, however.  If the hospital hosts foreign observers regularly, they may have someone on staff who is familiar with rhe process.  If so, you should ask that person what to do.